# Trigger on insert, update other table but only one row

Tags: mysql

i have 3 tables

table product ( PK id_product, qty_stock)  -- I have several products

table link  ( PK FK id_product, PK FK id_order) --  the foreign keys pointing to the other 2 tables

table order ( PK id_order, qty_bought)

**Question**
A trigger that subtracts qty_bought of qty_stock when a order row is created, the problem is that FOR EACH ROW subtracts to all the product rows and i cant find a way to tell which product because the order table has no id_product reference. Is there a solution or do i need to change the tables? Thx.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS OnInsertStock;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER OnInsertStock
  AFTER INSERT ON order FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    UPDATE product           
    SET qty_stock = qty_stock - new.qty_bought
  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an [Multi Table Update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html).

Join `product` and `link` and then update only fields from `product`.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS OnInsertStock;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER OnInsertStock
  AFTER INSERT ON order FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    UPDATE product, link
       SET product.qty_stock = product.qty_stock - new.qty_bought
     WHERE product.id_product = link.id_product
       AND link.id_order = new.id_order
  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Already tried that, but it still takes away from all the rows, instead of only the product inserted in the order

Comment: I've added the last part needed to the WHERE-part. You need to use id_order from the insert when selecting from the link-table

Comment: Like always end the problem was somewhere else, i forgot to insert info in link table simultaneously with the insert in order, however your answer was right and thx for the help.